# Woocommerce - save_account_details hook checks required fields even for a different form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, function, woocommerce

In woocommerce [form-edit-account.php](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-templates-myaccount-form-edit-account.html) I have an additional form that allows users to change their profile picture. Everything works fine but there is a small problem. When the user clicks Upload Avatar a function should be executed that updates the user's `image` meta_key through [update_user_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/). This is ok.

However the function is not executed because the `save_account_details` hook is looking for the fields (name, surname, email etc.) that are present in the original form but not in the second form I added. So how can I save the fields of the new form without having the save_account_details hook check the required fields ? I've seen a lot of questions with the solution of turning off required fields, but I don't want to turn them off.

Is there a way to save woocommerce form fields with a different hook?

I appreciate any help thanks.

This is the form I added to the original template [form-edit-account.php](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-templates-myaccount-form-edit-account.html) (I have not replaced but only added).

```
<!-- START FORM CHANGE SETTINGS -->
<form name="Form-Avatar" class="edit-avatar" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag' );?> >
  
  <!-- Avatar Section -->
  <div class="global_container avatar">

    <div class="avatar_col_1"><?php
      // Visualizza Avatar  
      if ($attachment_id) {
        $original_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id);
        // Display Image instead of URL
        echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, $size = array('150', '150')); // Invece dell'array size, stava 'full' come parametro.
      } else {
        ?><img style="" src="<?php echo get_avatar_url($user_id, array ('size' => 150)); ?>" alt=""><?php
      }
    ?></div>

    <div class="avatar_col_2">
      <div class="upload-field">
        <p class="form-row avatar">
          <div class="field-settings upload">
            <label for="file" class="chose_file_button">Scegli immagine</label>
            <label id="file-name" for="file" class="chose_file_input">Nessuna immagine selezionata</label>
          </div>  
          <input id="file" type="file" style="display:none;" class="field-settings avatar" name="image" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg">
          
          <span class="t4-light avatar"><?php esc_html_e( "File consentiti: png/gif/jpeg, dimensione massima 1MB. L'immagine del tuo profilo verrà visualizzata nelle recensioni dei prodotti e nei commenti.", 'woocommerce' ); ?></span>
        </p>
      </div>
      
      <!-- Show file name inside label avatar -->
      <script>
        $("#file").change(function(){
          $("#file-name").text(this.files[0].name);
        });
      </script>

      <div class="avatar_button">
        <!-- Upload Avatar -->
        <p style="margin-bottom: 0px!important;">
          <?php wp_nonce_field( 'save_account_details', 'save-account-details-nonce-avatar' ); ?>
          <button type="submit" class="edit-account-button" name="save_account_details" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Upload Avatar', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
          <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_account_details" />
        </p>
      
        <?php
          // Rimuovi immagine Button
          if (isset($_GET['rm_profile_image_id'])) {
            if ($attachment_id == $_GET['rm_profile_image_id']) {
              wp_delete_attachment($attachment_id);
              
              if (delete_user_meta($user_id, 'image')) {
                wp_delete_attachment($attachment_id);
              }

              ?><script>window.location='<?php echo wc_get_account_endpoint_url('impostazioni') ?>';</script><?php
              exit();
            }
          } else {
            echo '<a href=' . wc_get_account_endpoint_url('impostazioni') . '?rm_profile_image_id=' . $attachment_id . '> ' . __('Remove') . ' </a>';
          } 
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>      
</form>
```

This instead is the function of saving the meta_key 'image'

```
// Save Avatar Action
function action_woocommerce_save_account_details( $user_id ) {  
  if ( isset( $_FILES['image'] ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );

    // Imposta la cartella in cui salvare gli avatar degli utenti
    function wp_set_custom_upload_folder($uploads) {
      $uploads['path'] = $uploads['basedir'] . '/avatar-upload';
      $uploads['url'] = $uploads['baseurl'] . '/avatar-upload';    
      if (!file_exists($uploads['path'])) {
        mkdir($uploads['path'], 0755, true);
      }
      return $uploads;
    } add_filter('upload_dir', 'wp_set_custom_upload_folder');     
      
    $attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'image', 0 );

    if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
      update_user_meta( $user_id, 'image', $_FILES['image']['error'] . ": " . $attachment_id->get_error_message() );

    } else {
      $old_attachment_id = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'image', true );
      wp_delete_attachment($old_attachment_id);
      update_user_meta( $user_id, 'image', $attachment_id );
    } 
    remove_filter('upload_dir', 'wp_set_custom_upload_folder');
  }

} add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details', 'action_woocommerce_save_account_details', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try adding the form using hooks instead of overriding the template? I understand that you want a separate form altogether but this could be an alternate solution to it.

**1. Add your avatar field:**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form', 'add_avatar_to_edit_account_form' );
function add_avatar_to_edit_account_form() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_id = $user->ID;
    //Add all other relevant variables you need here to prefill the fields like $attachment_id etc.
    ?>
        <!-- Avatar Section -->
  <div class="global_container avatar">

    <div class="avatar_col_1"><?php
      // Visualizza Avatar  
      if ($attachment_id) {
        $original_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id);
        // Display Image instead of URL
        echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, $size = array('150', '150')); // Invece dell'array size, stava 'full' come parametro.
      } else {
        ?><img style="" src="<?php echo get_avatar_url($user_id, array ('size' => 150)); ?>" alt=""><?php
      }
    ?></div>

    <div class="avatar_col_2">
      <div class="upload-field">
        <p class="form-row avatar">
          <div class="field-settings upload">
            <label for="file" class="chose_file_button">Scegli immagine</label>
            <label id="file-name" for="file" class="chose_file_input">Nessuna immagine selezionata</label>
          </div>  
          <input id="file" type="file" style="display:none;" class="field-settings avatar" name="image" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg">
          <input id="current_image" type="text" style="display:none;" name="current_image" value="<?php if($attachment_id){echo $attachment_id;} ?>">
          
          <span class="t4-light avatar"><?php esc_html_e( "File consentiti: png/gif/jpeg, dimensione massima 1MB. L'immagine del tuo profilo verrà visualizzata nelle recensioni dei prodotti e nei commenti.", 'woocommerce' ); ?></span>
        </p>
      </div>
      
      <!-- Show file name inside label avatar -->
      <script>
        $("#file").change(function(){
          $("#file-name").text(this.files[0].name);
        });
      </script>

      <div class="avatar_button">
        <!-- Upload Avatar -->
        <p style="margin-bottom: 0px!important;">
          <?php wp_nonce_field( 'save_account_details', 'save-account-details-nonce-avatar' ); ?>
          <button type="submit" class="edit-account-button" name="save_account_details" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Upload Avatar', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
          <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_account_details" />
        </p>
      
        <?php
          // Rimuovi immagine Button
          if (isset($_GET['rm_profile_image_id'])) {
            if ($attachment_id == $_GET['rm_profile_image_id']) {
              wp_delete_attachment($attachment_id);
              
              if (delete_user_meta($user_id, 'image')) {
                wp_delete_attachment($attachment_id);
              }

              ?><script>window.location='<?php echo wc_get_account_endpoint_url('impostazioni') ?>';</script><?php
              exit();
            }
          } else {
            echo '<a href=' . wc_get_account_endpoint_url('impostazioni') . '?rm_profile_image_id=' . $attachment_id . '> ' . __('Remove') . ' </a>';
          } 
        ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>      
    <?php
}
```

**2. Save your avatar field:**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details', 'save_avatar_account_details', 12, 1 );
function save_avatar_account_details( $user_id ) {
    if (isset( $_POST['current_image'] ) && !isset($_FILES['image'])) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'image', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['current_image']) );
    } else if ( isset( $_FILES['image'] ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );

    // Imposta la cartella in cui salvare gli avatar degli utenti
    function wp_set_custom_upload_folder($uploads) {
      $uploads['path'] = $uploads['basedir'] . '/avatar-upload';
      $uploads['url'] = $uploads['baseurl'] . '/avatar-upload';    
      if (!file_exists($uploads['path'])) {
        mkdir($uploads['path'], 0755, true);
      }
      return $uploads;
    } add_filter('upload_dir', 'wp_set_custom_upload_folder');     
      
    $attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'image', 0 );

    if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
      update_user_meta( $user_id, 'image', $_FILES['image']['error'] . ": " . $attachment_id->get_error_message() );

    } else {
      $old_attachment_id = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'image', true );
      wp_delete_attachment($old_attachment_id);
      update_user_meta( $user_id, 'image', $attachment_id );
    } 
    remove_filter('upload_dir', 'wp_set_custom_upload_folder');
  }
}
```

**3. Add `multipart/form-data` to the form:**

```
// Add enctype to form to allow image upload
function add_multipart_to_woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag() {
    echo 'enctype="multipart/form-data"';
} 
add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag', 'add_multipart_to_woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag' );
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I appreciate it. I hate working with hooks because I don't have the freedom to place elements where I want in the html structure. For example, the form-edit-account.php template only provides four hooks `woocommerce_edit_account_form`, `woocommerce_edit_account_form_start`, `woocommerce_edit_account_form_end`, `woocommerce_after_edit_account_form` and I don't want to place the avatar's html in any of the positions proposed by the hooks. Maybe I can create a custom hook to place it where I want inside template ?

Comment: Yes. You can override the template just to add your own hook at the required position. And change the hook in my code.

Comment: Replace the "woocommerce_edit_account_form" hook in my code with your custom hook.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion is working, but I have the problem I was trying to solve by implementing a separate form solution. In practice, when I click on the save settings button, the entire form is sent, so the avatar field is also updated.

If the user has not uploaded any images, the field is updated and the previous image is deleted. So if the user wants to change only the name and save the settings, he will find himself without an avatar.

Comment: Yes, I had seen your earlier questions and I think I added my suggestions to them too. To solve the issue you mentioned I'd suggest prefilling the avatar field with the current avatar of the user. that way you'll never lose it.

Comment: You are very kind, I really appreciate the time you are dedicating to me. I hadn't thought about it, I'll try even if I'm not really sure how to do it. If you could suggest me how I would have a reference point on how to do it.

Comment: I've updated my code to accommodate your requirement to keep the existing image in place.

Comment: Thanks for editing the answer, just tried it, but it gets deleted anyway. Could this be the problem? `else { $ old_attachment_id = get_user_meta ($ user_id, 'image', true); wp_delete_attachment ($ old_attachment_id); update_user_meta ($ user_id, 'image', $ attachment_id); }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247657/discussion-between-vinay-jain-and-snorlax).

Comment: Ok, I just entered `$prev_value = ''` in `update_user_meta` and it's working, I didn't think it was that simple.